# preg_match from this code

Tags: php, preg-match

Hi if someone could help me with my preg_match I want the title from this code

```
    <dt class="gallery-icon">
    <a href="?attachment_id=31" title="title">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="librosdefirmas-bodas-1-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Caption">
    </a>
</dt>
```

i have this:

```
preg_match_all('/<dt class="gallery-icon">\s*<a href="(.*)" title="(.*)".*>/is', $page_columns[0], $titles);
```

But it doesn't work who can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't parse HTML with regular expressions. [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php/3577662#3577662).

```
$html = '
 <dt class="gallery-icon">
    <a href="?attachment_id=31" title="title">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="librosdefirmas-bodas-1-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Caption">
    </a>
</dt>
';
$dom_document = new DOMDocument();
$dom_document->loadHTML($html);
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom_document);
$elements = $dom_xpath->query("//dt/a");
print_r( $elements->item(0)->getAttribute('title') );
```

Answer (score 1):

The ".*" is a greedy match, i.e. it'll wander outside of the first quote if there is a later one that it can match. Use [^"]* instead of .* to match all characters but a quote.

Comment: `/<dt class="gallery-icon">\s*<a href="[^"]*" title="([^"]*)".*>/is` full pattern which gived the `title` in first group